# Multirow figure gets cutoff when generating a PDF via Quarto

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, quarto

I am creating a PDF using Quarto. I have several instances in which I am using [subfigures](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/figures.html#subfigures). The subfigures are large, and have to remain large - each component of the subfigure should be approximately the size of the page. The problem is that when rendering to PDF, the second subfigure does not float to the next page - instead it is placed below the first.

Here is a reproducible example, using images taken from this Wikipedia article downloaded at original resolution.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petasites_hybridus

```
---
title: "test"

format:
  html:
    theme: cosmo
  pdf:
    documentclass: scrreprt
    include-in-header: 
      text: |
        \usepackage{booktabs}
        \usepackage{longtable}
        \usepackage{array}
        \usepackage{multirow}
        \usepackage{wrapfig}
        \usepackage{float}
        \usepackage{colortbl}
        \usepackage{pdflscape}
        \usepackage{tabu}
        \usepackage{threeparttable}
        \usepackage{threeparttablex}
        \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
        \usepackage{makecell}
        \usepackage{xcolor}
  docx: default
editor: visual
---

test

::: {#fig-flower layout-nrow="2"}
![](images/Petasites_hybridus_inflorescence_-_Keila.jpg)

![](images/Petasites_hybridus_leaf.JPG)
:::
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but don't use the tabu package with current latex. It is more or less completely broken and just held together with a bit of duck tape.

Comment: Any response to this issue?